# Detecting palms on a touch screen

Tags: multi-touch, gesture-recognition, interaction, user-interaction, nui

everyone!

I'm doing a research project involving detecting the simultaneous detection of palms placed on a multitouch screen.
I've done quite a bit googling and found out that there's a lot of libraries both for gesture recognition (AS3, https://github.com/fljot/Gestouch for instance) and computer vision. I'm working with JSTouchController (https://github.com/sebleedelisle/JSTouchController), but it  tracks only 5 fingers at a time. So if I place one palm on a screen and the library finds all five fingers, it won't track second palm being placed at all. It works correctly from time to time, though.

So, the question is: are there any libraries to track ten fingers simultaneously with acceptable quality on modern touch screens?

Comment: Who tracks 5 fingers?? That JSTouchController uses regular javascript touch events and it doesn't limit anything to 5 or other number. So it must be browser/device, right?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, Pavel. My mistake. I'll update the question.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of touch points is usually restricted by the device or OS. If you want to prototype something quickly, one possibility is to use the LEAP motion sensor. It can track ten fingers in front of it, although not via touch.